# Why can't I create new posts in Wordpress? Warning: Creating default object from empty value in /public_html/wp-admin/includes/post.php on line 716

Tags: php, database, wordpress, auto-increment

I have run into a problem where I can no longer create new posts on my Wordpress site.

I think this started after a Wordpress update a while ago. I also have problems uploading images and I see ghost comments (an icon about new comments but no comments actually showing up in the list).

When clicking on "Posts > Add new" I get a white page with this warning:

"Warning: Creating default object from empty value in /public_html/wp-admin/includes/post.php on line 716"

This is line 716:

```
    $post->post_content = (string) apply_filters( 'default_content', $post_content, $post );
```

After searching online I think these issues are related to my database. I'm new to dealing with databases, so I'm hoping to maybe be able to get some help here.

**Things I've tried:**

- Using a standard theme
- Disabling all plugins
- Updating Wordpress
- Downgrading to Wordpress 4.0
- Repairing the database tables
- Running health check I found out that the SQL is old
  (5.5.52-MariaDB-cll-lve). Could this be relevant?
- Checked the AUTO_INCREMENT box in phpMyAdmin for "wp_posts > structure > ID" and
  "wp_postmeta > structure > idmeta_id"

The auto_increment helped remove the error, but instead it caused some new problems. I activated it and could click "Posts > Add new". However, Wordpress created multiple copies of the same post, around fifteen posts instead of just one. I trashed them and tried to create a new post, but it still remembered the trashed post and tried to recreate a new post from the post in the trash.

**Links I've checked and tried:**

- https://wordpress.org/support/topic/creating-default-object-from-empty-value-of-line-639-wp-adminincludespostphp/
- https://wordpress.org/support/topic/shoud-wp_posts-id-and-wp_post_meta-meta_id-be-auto_increment/

**I feel like this could be relevant as well, but I'm not sure how to make use of it:**

- https://wpindexfixer.tools.managedwphosting.nl/

Comment: Please provide complete code.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Mulli! I ended up reinstalling wordpress, will write an answer about it below.

Comment: I had a similar problem that was caused by a caching plugin (SiteGround Optimizer). I solved it by clearing the cache.

Answer (score 9):

The error is because of the Auto_increment being disabled for the column ID of the table **wp_posts**. You can enable the Auto Increment option from the **PhpMyAdmin**.

> wp_posts -> Structure -> Change option for column ID -> Check the AUTO_INCREMENT option -> Save.

You could run the following query within the database:

> ALTER TABLE `wp_posts` CHANGE `ID` `ID` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;`

You may also need to enable Auto increment for the table **wp_postmeta**.

Comment: WOOO! thanks for this! solved my problem. I wonder if I should add AUTO INCREMENT in every structure ID in all the database

Answer (score 1):

**Update: Just want to make clear that this is a workaround, I still don't know exactly what the issue was.**

Leaving this here in case someone else encounters the same issue. I asked my brother for help and since there were so many weird errors we decided to reinstall wordpress. This is how we did it:

1. Took a backup with the Tools > Export option
2. Went into the wp-config file and changed the table prefix name to a completely new one. $table_prefix  = 'changethisname';
3. Went to mysite.com/wp-admin and filled in the info in the WordPress installation.
4. Went to Tools > Import > WordPress. Included attachments.
5. It took about half an hour for all of the content to reappear, but it seems to be working correctly now.

Comment: This is not an answer since you did not find the source of the problem - Only a workaround. In addition, changing the table prefix the way you diid may lead you to other issues.
I suggest - start a new wordpres site and perform export/import to the post as you did.

Comment: Hello again @Mulli! I'll rephrase it so that it's clear that it is a workaround. I did first try adding a completely new wordpress without changing the table prefix, but then I had the same error with the posts. So it seems to have been related to the old database table somehow. 
No new issues with the site so far at least, will update this post if I notice something. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

In my case , did all the things that you say , i found that the next auto increment value was equal to the last post ID( 500 ) in wp_posts table,then i added one to the auto-incremenet value ( 501 ) and sucessful.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED upping the memory limit on Mysql

Answer (score 0):

Head to Phpmyadmin dashboard and try to find posts table, (it can also be in the name for example : `abc_posts`),  -> go to structure, ->, then select ID, -> if Null is selected to auto increment, deselect, hit save then again, select Auto increment(AI), then save again. Try this, it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue on a website I was working on by toggling the Auto Increment in the database. At first I couldn't create new posts, pages, or upload images. I tried deactivating all plugins and updating everything but still no go. I realized it's a database issue.

I fixed this by going to **wp_posts** table in the database. Then go to Structure and then edit the first row which is **ID**.  I then toggled the **A_I** box and saved.

You can find the breakdown solution here:
http://simplify.quedank.com/how-to-fix-warning-creating-default-object-from-empty-value-in-in-wordpress/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

**If you are getting the error in post.php line 708**

Check the tables auto-increment and primary key feature.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error, and the issue was that the Mysql space was full. I just added more MB to my database and everything worked fine